# Can an array of a specific number of references be passed as a parameter to a function?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

If I want to pass a specific number of references to a method, how can I do it?

e.g.

```
public void getArr(CP[] c,String t)
{
    for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
        cp[nr]=c[nr];
        nr++;
    }
}
```

I want for example my method to take exactly an array of 3 references to CP objects;how can I specify that in the method?

Comment: Array length is not part of the type, so it can't be enforced via the method signature. You could have 3 parameters instead; but I guess you want something less clunky than that.

Comment: Yes :) .Could it be done with collections?

Comment: Only if you have a custom collection specifically designed to hold 3 elements. Again, size is not part of a collection's type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in java as the length of the array is not a part of its type. You can workaround it with a check at runtime:

```
public void getArr(CP[] c,String t)
{
    if (c.length != 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Required exactly 3 array elements");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
        cp[nr]=c[nr];
        nr++;
    }
}
```

Or with `assert`:

```
public void getArr(CP[] c,String t)
{
    assert c.length == 3 : "Required exactly 3 array elements";
    for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
        cp[nr]=c[nr];
        nr++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Java.

`CP[]` is the *type* for `c`; the specific size of the array does not form part of the type. So you can't induce a compile-time failure.

If you don't want to rely on run-time checks, why not pass `CP c1, CP c2, CP c3` instead and break up the array at the call site?